# Minimum work on a plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction

Consider a block placed on a rough horizontal surface where the frictional coefficient between the surface and the block is $\mu$. Suppose I need to find the minimum force that must be exerted to make the block move.

I believe that, intuitively, this force should equal the frictional force i.e. $\mu mg$. But my textbook says that the value of minimum force is lower than that. How can a force smaller than the limiting friction move the object?

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think it is a fairly conceptual question stated in a bad way-like a homework-type question. (Just my opinion, of course)

Comment: @Krishna It does look like, with a *radical* rephrasing, the core of this post could be turned into an on-topic question. However, in its current phrasing, this is absolutely the type of question that the site consensus dictates should be closed.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, yes, I agree with you. I just noted that it has the potential to become a conceptual question- I'm not opposed to it being closed in this form.

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal I have suggested an edit for your question since it was a badly presented conceptual question. If you disagree with the edit, you may disapprove/approve if it doesn't matter. And try to avoid using numbers-it makes the question feel like a homework exercise and gets you the infamous 'homework tag'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is a very common confusion among students. Most people assume that the frictional force is given by $f=\mu mg$, but actually, the expression for friction looks like this
$$f=\mu N$$ where $N$ is the Normal force acting on the body.

Suppose you exert a force obliquely. In that case, your force can be broken into a horizontal and vertical component. The vertical component will decrease the 'weight' of the body i.e. the Normal force decreases.

This means that the limiting value of friction will also become lower, and the horizontal component of the applied force should equal (or overcome) this new frictional decreased frictional force. With a little bit of calculus, you'll reach the answer.

Comment: Please don't answer bad-quality homework questions -- this type of answer simply encourages other users to post help-vampire threads. Providing this sort of answer *before* OP fixes their post simply removes any incentive for them to fix it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty OK. I shall delete it till the OP fixes it.